# Masking network behind another using Iptables MARK and NETMAP targets

Tags: iptables, nat, ipsec, strongswan, mapping

Aoa,
Hello I have faced similar scinario mentioned in following link during vpn tunnel implementation using Strongswan:

https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/net2net-same-nets/

Here it is mention that:
**necessary network mappings are done on gateway sun using the iptables MARK and NETMAP targets.**

But I dont know to add these configuration mappings and iptables.

My Configuration IPs with gateways are mentioned below and **I have to mask one network behind another network:**

**Cli1(10.10.3.12) gw(10.10.3.1)---(10.10.3.10) gw(10.10.3.1)Dev1(192.168.0.2) gw(192.168.0.1)====(192.168.0.3) gw(192.168.0.1)Dev2(10.10.3.11) gw(10.10.3.1)---(10.10.3.13) gw(10.10.3.1)Cli2**

Here I have to mask 10.10.3.0/24 network with another network at both source and destination ends.
Kindly guide me how to do this.
Thanks

Comment: On your link, check the `iptables-save` on the sun gateway. You'll find the full rule set with example.

Comment: by writing this command: only shows 500 and 4500/udp allow etc., but in the link there is mentioned of masking one network behind another how I add this to my iptables.